# Beatifying argparse string

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string of input arguments:

`--device dev1 --device_file /path/to/file --telnet_xr_username cisco --force_ssh --sim_start --sim_schema schema.yaml --sim_connect --extra_params "-cov -p --glv" --webreport --diag scneario_name`

and I want to write a program to add a new line between each option and print it. So the output will look like this:

```
--device dev1 
--device_file /path/to/file 
--telnet_xr_username cisco 
--force_ssh 
--sim_start 
--sim_schema schema.yaml 
--sim_connect 
--extra_params "-cov -p --glv" 
--webreport 
--diag scneario_name
```

The list of options varies. The program can receive any number of options. However, an option's format is either

`--option`

or

`--option <value>`

What's the most efficient and pythonic way to do this? (specially for large strings)

Comment: Do you want to specify long string at the terminal? Or you have that string in python program and you want to print it to terminal?

Comment: The latter case. I want to print it in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what "beatify" means, but this seems like a shell parser issue, not Python

A backslash (with no trailing spaces) is a line continuation

```
python script.py \
  --device dev1 \
  --device_file /path/to/file \
  --telnet_xr_username cisco \
  --force_ssh \
  ...
```

> What's the most efficient and pythonic way to do this?

Use a config file rather than a chain of CLI arguments

Comment: I edited my question. I hope its more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own parser and then ingest the string to it. Then iterate over the parser options.
See an example below:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--abc")
parser.add_argument("--xyz", action='store_true')

string_to_parse = '--xyz --abc some/file/location'
string_to_parse = string_to_parse.split() # because we expect args in form of sys.argv[1:]

options = parser.parse_args(string_to_parse)
for arg in vars(options):
    print(f'--{arg} {getattr(options,arg)}')
```

which on running gives me:

```
--abc some/file/location
--xyz True
```